# Passing data from parent to child via props in v-for in VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I went through similar questions but I couldn't find the answer and none of them worked for me.

[Vuejs v-for Passing data Parent to Child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331784/vuejs-v-for-passing-data-parent-to-child)

[Vue - Passing parent data with same key name in v-for to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596517/vue-passing-parent-data-with-same-key-name-in-v-for-to-child-component)

[vue js how to pass data from parent, v-for loop list to child component with method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956778/vue-js-how-to-pass-data-from-parent-v-for-loop-list-to-child-component-with-met)

[Pass data object from parent to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313990/pass-data-object-from-parent-to-child-component)

[Vue.js - Pass in Multiple Props to Child in V-For](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409732/vue-js-pass-in-multiple-props-to-child-in-v-for)

[VUE / VUEX: How To Pass Data From Parent Template To Child Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225779/vue-vuex-how-to-pass-data-from-parent-template-to-child-template)

Parent.vue

```
            <div class="col-sm-2" v-for="(item,index) in itemsData" :key="index">
              <ItemWidget :item="item" />
            </div>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from "vuex";

import ItemWidget from "@/components/item/ItemWidget";

export default {
  components: { ItemWidget },
  computed: {
    ...mapState("item", ["itemsData"])
  },
  created() {
    this.getItemList();
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions("item", ["getItemListX"]),
    getItemList() {
      this.getItemListX();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

ItemWidget.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="label">
      <div class="label-value">{{ item.code }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["item"]
};
</script>
```

itemsData is taken from the vuex by using MapState to the parent and itemsData is populated using created() method in the parent via an axios call in the vuex.

Error 1.

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.item is undefined"
```

Error 2.

```
TypeError: "_vm.item is undefined"
```

How can I fix this?

Update

```
  itemsData: [
    {
      code: "Test",
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Can you show how your itemsData looks like ?

Comment: This could be easier to debug if you could provide an example repo.

Answer (score 0):

You should populate itemsData in computed method using ...mapState

Parent.vue

```
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: this.itemsData
    }
  },
  computed:{
    ...mapState('module/namespace', ['itemsData'])
  }

}

<div class="col-sm-2" v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index">
    <ItemWidget :item="item" />
</div>
```

There is another way to declare your props:

```
<template>
    <div class="label">
      <div class="label-value">{{ item.code }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    type: Object,
    default: null
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Read the question, please. I have added mapState

Comment: mapState could go in computed and not in created instead!

Comment: Yes in the computed

Comment: update the question with the code in your parent! :)

Comment: Updated! Please check

Comment: 1- Can you print please <pre>itemsData</pre> in the template and check the data there? 2- can you please see where is the error coming from? I am guessing is from the child component .

Comment: 1. Yes I have set sample data as shared above.
2. Yes from child component

Comment: maybe axios take some time to get the data and the component wants to render it. take this try:

Comment: [Vue warn]: The computed property "itemsData" is already defined in data.

Comment: do you have more stuff in data(){} ? itemsData should be declared there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197709/discussion-between-ezequiel-fernandez-and-techie).